# Can't view folder tree in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have recently created a new user in SQL Server. I want this user to only have reading and writing abilities on certain DBs. I have `db_reader` and `db_writer` enabled on the database in question BUT I get the below error when trying to view the tables in the folder tree in SQL Server. I have double checked to make sure DENY was not enabled for this user.

[SQL ERROR 229](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HML6k.png)

I deleted the user, same error. I created a different user with same permissions, same error, I enabled `db_reader` and `db_writer` on this database and the `master` and `MSDB` databases, and still got the same error. I do not want to give them the `db_owner` role to fix this issue.

Comment: Is the error that the user can't view Object Explorer in SSMS or that they can't run queries?

Comment: the error happens in ssms when i want to expand the tables folder in the folder tree on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the user mapping that Default Schema is sys instead of dbo.

Comment: it was set to DBO, i changed it to SYS and still got the same error.

Comment: Under the user's security, Securables, tick grant for 'view server state'

Comment: Still, no dice....

Answer (score 0):

your problem related to with use query store

Just use

```
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO [USER];
```

You can create Login and User and grant  with the following statements:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [Testu] WITH PASSWORD=N'123', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

use [TestDB]
go
CREATE USER [Testu] FOR LOGIN [Testu]
GO
use [TestDB]
go
GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO [Testu];
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [Testu]
```

Comment: did that, still getting the error. I'm setting up the user with windows credentials, should i use the SQL option?

Comment: It doesn't matter.i am checking with sql db user.can you test with other db or new db ?do you want to send my code?